# Communication between a Switch and Router?

Tags: routing, switch, router, switching

When a computer, **Computer A**, wants to communicate with **Computer B**, it (Computer A) will use **MAC** and **IP** addresses. It will send the packet of information to **Switch**, which, based upon the **MAC** destination address contained in the packet of information, will look on its lookup table if the computer that owns the mentioned MAC Destination Address is available on the **LAN** network, right?

If it is unable to locate the computer on the LAN (suppose here that the lookup table is full), will it send it to **Router**, or does **Computer A** decide to send directly to the **MAC** address of the **Network Interface Card** of **Router** (the link with the WAN or the Internet for my LAN)?

I am a little bit confused related to the way that switches communicate with routers. When and how is this done?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A host will first determine if the destination IP address is on the same network. If not, it will send the IP packet to its configured gateway.

A switch doesn't decide this, and, to a switch, a router is just another host. The MAC address to which a frame is delivered is determined by the host before the host encapsulates the packet in a frame.

Comment: you mean **CA** decides and knows that the IP destination address of **CB** is not on the network ?

Comment: I still don't get it ?

Comment: Frame is an information packet, right ? you mean by host : Computer A or Computer B ?

Comment: Exactly, A host has a configured IP address and mask. It masks its IP address to get its network. It will mask a destination address to get the network of the destination. If the two networks are not identical, it knows that the destination is on a different network. If the destination is on a different network, it will send the packet to its configured gateway.

Comment: A frame is a layer-2 datagram, and a packet is a layer-3 datagram. A packet has the layer-3 (IP) source and destination addresses. A frame has the layer-2 (MAC) source and destination addresses. A layer-4 datagram (TCP/UDP) has layer-4 source and destination addresses (ports).

Comment: excellent point, I see more clear now, but by Gateway you mean the Router ? sorry you are using a different terminology ...

Comment: A gateway can be, and usually is, a router. A gateway is a host term which means the address to which it should send packets which are not on the same network. Switches don't know anything about gateways or routers; they are just hosts to a switch.

Comment: So if I got what you mean, the Computer A knows from the Packet that the destination host is not on the local network. but since it has no choice it will send it to the switch, which will switch it to the Router. in order to this to be done, the packet must contain a frame that has router NIC MAC address as a destination MAC address ? right ?

Comment: Segments (layer-4 datagram) get encapsulated by packets (layer-3 datagrams), which in turn get encapsulated by frames (layer-2 datagrams), which get turned into bits on the wire. The switch will look at the frame to see the MAC addresses, and it will switch the frame to the port where the destination MAC address is connected. A router will strip off the frame and switch the packet to a different router interface, where it will build a new frame for the new interface.

Comment: wow, I love network engineering :D thank you so much @Maupin ... you deserve your 16.300 reputation points... good luck and thank you again for the explanation.

Comment: You should look at [this document](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwjlv6X_nP3LAhVhkIMKHRo6C5YQFgguMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com%2Fimages%2F0131014684%2Fsamplechapter%2F0131014684_ch02.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFok2P1RgS2aLdc0nwE6OVOLiLv9g&sig2=gORz_Ib9rj22iZbJ5RRvmQ&cad=rja).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly when computer A is initiating  traffic to computer B . ComputerA runs ANDing process to know whether source and destination are in same networks or different networks

**If same networks**

Packet will be forwarded to layer2 which is connected directly to Computer A . In Switch layer2 lookup is verified mac address of destination is checked with mac -address table of switch and frame is forwarded accordinglly with the mac -address in switch .
.
**If different networks**

Packet will be forwarded to gateway of computerA  . From gateway it's will forward to further destination based of routing table in layer3 device .